# WordPress wp_count_terms() number of tags

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I want to count the number of terms in my own Custom Post Type. I use the following code:

```
$posttags = the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'yacht-detail');
$count = wp_count_terms($posttags);
echo $count;
```

The code is working, but it counts every word, not every term. I have two- or three-word-terms. And `wp_count_terms` counts every word.

How can I achieve the right counting?

Comment: `the_terms` prints the terms in a list. Use `wp_get_post_terms`, that will give you an array, then just `count` it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `yacht-detail` is your taxonomy

```
$count = wp_count_terms('yacht-detail');
echo $count;
```